# リモートシェルでローカルシェルの変数を参照したい

Tags: bash, ssh, sed

ローカルで定義、初期化した変数を使ってリモートシェル上でsedコマンドを使いたいと考えております。
例を示すと

```
local.sh
#!/bin/bash
string="hello"
ssh host  'sed -i -e s/world/${string}/g /home/user/test.txt'
```

このスクリプトを実行した際にリモート上のtest.txtでworld -> hello の置換が実行されることが理想です。
この時どのように変数を指定すればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: `ssh host "sed -i -e s/world/${string}/g /home/user/test.txt"` とするのはどうでしょう？

Comment: metropolis様

コメントありがとうございます。
ご指摘通りダブルクオーテーションで囲んでもから文字が出力され、置換結果が
空行となりました。
そこで、置換分(s/.../.../g)をシングルクオートで囲むことで置換前に変数が評価され理想通りの結果となりました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fumiyas さんもおっしゃっていますが、 sed と ssh 組み合わせてやろうとすると、いくつか制御文字が使われた場合などで、バグが発生しています。まず具体例から。

質問者さんがやりたいことは、 world -> hello であるならば、ひとまず以下で達成できます。

```bash
: ${SSH_TO:=host}
TARGET_FILE=/home/ec2-user/test.txt
FROM_STRING=world
TO_STRING=hello
ssh "$SSH_TO" sed -e "s/${FROM_STRING}/${TO_STRING}/g" $TARGET_FILE
```

しかしこれは、変数に sed の制御文字が入ってきた時点で正しく動作しなくなってしまいます。

```bash
: ${SSH_TO:=host}
TARGET_FILE=/home/ec2-user/test.txt
FROM_STRING=world
TO_STRING=hel/lo
ssh "$SSH_TO" sed -e "s/${FROM_STRING}/${TO_STRING}/g" $TARGET_FILE
# sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown option to `s'
```

これを解消するためには、 sed ではなく awk を用います。awk だと環境変数から直接文字列を参照できます。また、 ssh は引数をスペースでつなげて文字列として対象ホストで実行します。これを正しく取り扱うために、環境変数のセットコマンドにはエスケープを施します。これをスクリプトにすると次。

```bash
#!/bin/sh

awk_script() {
    cat <<"EOF"
{ gsub(ENVIRON["FROM_STRING"], ENVIRON["TO_STRING"]); print }
EOF
}

# 1: var_name
# 2: content
ssh_set_variable() {
    cat <<EOF
${1}='$(printf '%s\n' "$2" | sed -e "s/'/\\'/g")'
EOF
}

: ${SSH_TO:=host}
TARGET_FILE=/home/ec2-user/test.txt
TO_STRING='any string should be allowed...'
FROM_STRING=world  # any should be OK also
ssh "$SSH_TO" \
    "$(ssh_set_variable FROM_STRING "${FROM_STRING}") " \
    "$(ssh_set_variable TO_STRING "${TO_STRING}") " \
    awk \'"$(awk_script)"\' \'"${TARGET_FILE}"\'
```

スクリプトの解説を書こうと思いましたが、このスクリプトを書くので力尽きてしまったので、ひとまず動くものを共有しています。。

Comment: fumiyasさんの指摘の趣旨は「制御文字が入ると誤動作する」ことではなく、「変数展開がどこでどのように行われてるのか意識せよ」という事だと思います。

Answer (score 4):

sshでリモート側にローカルの環境変数を渡すためには双方に設定が必要です。

### ローカル側

.ssh/config(または/etc/sshd/ssh_config)に環境変数を送信する設定

```
SendEnv string
```

### リモート側

/etc/ssh/sshd_configにローカル側が送ってきた環境変数を受け入れる設定

```
AcceptEnv string
```

また、現状のスクリプトでは`string`はexportされてないので子プロセスからは参照されません。

```
export string="hello"
```

として環境変数として設定してください。

Answer (score -1):

解決しました。

```
string="hello"
sed -i -e "sed -i -e 's/world/$string/g' /home/user/text.txt"
```

でできました

Comment: これは変数を渡しているわけではなく、ローカルのシェルが変数展開して、その結果がリモートに渡されています。どこで何がどのように解釈するのかをちゃんと意識しないとバグ(脆弱性を含む)の原因になりますよ。